# Best way to display a 2D shape from x,y positions unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, renderer

I would like to find the best way (or at least a working way) to display in my UI a custom 2D shape from the position of all its points.

I have tried :
 - to create a mesh (using a triangulator script to convert my (x,y) to the vertices+triangles, with a mesh renderer and a mesh filter. It seems to work but it not rendered in my UI even if its parent is a canvas (screen overlay).
 - Creating a Canvasrenderer and setting my mesh inside it using SetMesh, but nothing seems to be displayed. Here is my code if it's the good way to do it :

```
GameObject shapeChild = new GameObject();
            var shapeChildMeshRenderer = shapeChild.AddComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
            shapeChildMeshRenderer.SetMaterial(material, null);


            // Use the triangulator to get indices for creating triangles
            Triangulator tr = new Triangulator(part.Points);
            int[] indices = tr.Triangulate();

            // Create the Vector3 vertices
            Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[vertices2D.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(vertices2D[i].x, vertices2D[i].y, 0);
            }

            // Create the mesh
            Mesh _mesh = new Mesh();
            _mesh.vertices = vertices;
            _mesh.triangles = indices;
            _mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            _mesh.RecalculateBounds();

            shapeChildMeshRenderer.SetMesh(_mesh);

            shapeChild.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
```

I would like to keep the Screen Overlay setting.

What would be the best way to render my polygon in my overlay UI ?

Comment: Make it as a `UIPanel` ? Not as a mesh

Comment: How would you do that ? Do you have an example ? I can't find any

Comment: On the first page in google i had this example https://answers.unity.com/questions/1034060/create-unity-ui-panel-via-script.html

Comment: How is it linked to my issue ? If I don't use a Mesh how do I create a shape from the (x,y) coordinates ?

Comment: You want to create a shape without switching screen overlay setting